# How many memory is needed for this permutations?

Tags: permutation

That's the code.

```
Permutations[Alphabet[] , {12}]
```

The pop-up message said that the current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.
Is there any good ways to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to compute how many results there are? I think it is quite obvious why there couldn't possibly be enough memory for this. There would be $26!/(26 - 12)! = 4\,626\,053\,752\,320\,000$ results.

Comment: I am voting to close as "simple mistake".

Comment: Relevant reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion

Comment: BTW this also illustrates why designs that can generate the first `n` permutations (or whatever combinatorial object) are superior to Mathematica's usual approach of generating all of them at once. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations In Python you can process the first 100 objects, then do something else, then come back to request the next 100.

Comment: Last comment: if you are seriously interested in the properties of the set of these permutations, you have no hope of generating the entire set, ever. But you _can_ sample from it uniformly, and analyse the properties of a reasonable-sized sample. Check `RandomSample`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Mathematica definitely needs an integral approach for batch-processing long lists like this.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\frac{26!}{(26 - 12)!} \approx 4.6 \times 10^{15}$ permutations of length $12$ of the alphabet. (`N[26!/14!]`)

A crude estimate for the bytes needed to store the permutations can be obtained by looking at the behavior for short permutation sequences and extrapolating using a simple model.

```
data = ByteCount@Permutations[Alphabet[], {#}] & /@ Range[1, 5];
model = a 26!/(26 - n)!;
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a}, n];
Show[ListLogPlot[data], LogPlot[model /. fit, {n, 1, 12}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Crude extrapolation]

This gives an estimate for permutations of length `12`

```
model /. fit /. n -> 12
(* 1.146878404656574`*^18 *)
```